# Learning JAVA need help understanding the concept of getLogger().info() (Method Chaining)

Tags: java, methods, bukkit, chaining

I got stuck with the following line of code:

```
getLogger().info("Text Goes Here");  // This command outputs the text to console
```

I understand the basics on how objects work and are called, but in the videos that I watched on youtube, vivz (the author), never explained about calling methods inside methods (at least that's what I think is happening in the above code).

He explained about

```
ClassName.variable
xVariable.method()
```

but nothing related to

```
someMethod().anotherMethod();
```

in beginners terms, could anyone explain the concept or some explanation on what is going on here?

Basically, I want to know if `info()` is a method inside `getLogger()`, or what is `getLogger()` and `info()` in this case?

Comment: It is not method inside method, these are two method calls. First `getLogger()` is called and on the return value (object) next `info(String)` is called.

Comment: hmm is it something like piping in linux?
`cat filename | grep matchingtext`

Comment: In a sense yes. Here we use the return object from the previous call to perform the next operation. So for example, instead of calling the `concat()` you can call the `trim()` or `length()` method on the returned instance. If the returned instance is of different from `String`, then you can call/perform the operations defined for that operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is called [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).**

> Method chaining is a common syntax for `invoking multiple method calls` in object-oriented programming languages. Each method returns an object, allowing the calls to be chained together in a single statement without requiring variables to store the intermediate results.

It is not method inside method, these are two method calls. First `getLogger()` is called and on the return value (object) next `info(String)` is called. You are chaining the two method calls in a single statement.

I will give you an example to understand this using `String.concat()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String first = "First";
  // Storing the resulting instance and then call again.
  String s1 = first.concat(" Second");
  s1 = s1.concat(" Third.");

  System.out.println(s1);
  // This is method chaining using String class with concat() method.
  String s2 = first.concat(" Second").concat(" Third.");
  System.out.println(s2);  
}
```

Here `String.concat()` returns the instance of `String` after the concatenation. Now you have the option of storing the instance in a variable and then again call the `concat()` on that or using the same instance directly.

Comment: aha! so method chaining. Thank you!, ill read more on it. Thanks your example helped me understand it better!

Answer (score 2):

what happens when calling `getLogger().info("Text Goes Here");`? First, with `getLogger()` you call a method which returns a logger object (class). In a second step, you call `info("Text goes Here")` on the logger object. It's quite common the chain method calls.

Answer (score 0):

`getLogger()` method returns an `Object`. Then you call `info()` method. This is a shorthand way called method chaining. If you want you can split this into two lines.

```
Logger logger = getLogger();
logger.info("Text goes Here");
```

This works as same as `getLogget().info("Text goes here");