# How can you invoke a method in Java class without using its class?

Tags: java, oop, javafx

In OOP, I learned that we can call a method by using its class.

For example:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.methodA(); // calling the method in person class
```

Based on javafx docs of ListView [(link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html)
, The getSelectionModel() is a method of a class ListView (okay working). But the selectedItemProperty() method is the class of SelectionModel [(link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html)

How can you call a method selectedItemProperty() without using its SelectionModel class? And what class does this addListener method came from?

```
myListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TodoItem>() {
///  blah blah blah
}
});
```

Comment: No. Even if you use reflection, the class is still involved. There's no need to import it, since you don't declare any variables of that type, but this does not change the fact that a method returning a `SelectionModel` instance is used. As for the `addListener` method. Take a look at the methods of [`ReadOnlyObjectProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyObjectProperty.html). It's down in the `ObservableValue` section...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `ListView#getSelectionModel()` you are getting an object which is an instance of `SelectionModel`—more specifically, an instance of `MultipleSelectionModel`. Since you now have an instance of `MultipleSelectionModel` you can invoke methods present in that class, including inherited methods. This means you can do the following:

```java
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(yourChangeListener);
```

Which is equivalent to the following:

```java
MultipleSelectionModel<T> sModel = listView.getSelectionModel();
ReadOnlyObjectProperty<T> selectedItemProp = sModel.selectedItemProperty();
selectedItemProp.addListener(yourChangeListener);
```

As you can see, you are using the class of every object involved. The former, known as method chaining, is just shorthand.

Comment: Method chaining isn't familiar to me. But now that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`MultipleSelectionModel` ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html)) extends `SelectionModel` ([link](http://selectedItemProperty)), in which the `selectedItemProperty()` method is implemented.

`selectedItemProperty()` returns a `ReadOnlyObjectProperty` ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyObjectProperty.html)) instance, which extends `ObservableValue` ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html)), from which the `addListener()` method is coming.

As for how you can call these methods- this is just how inheritance works. The subclass (`MultipleSelectionModel`) inherits all of the properties of its superclass (`SelectionModel`). Thus any methods defined in `SelectionModel` you can call against a `MultipleSelectionModel` instance.

[OOP Concept for Beginners: What is Inheritance?](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-inheritance/)

Comment: I understand that I can call the method of a superclass from a subclass. But how can you call 2 methods at the same time? 

'Emma emma = new Emma(); // extends Person class'
'emma.methodA.methodB(); //this is confusing'

Comment: Also i'm aware of inheritance. But I still don't understand how is this SelectionModel class related to ListView if the ListView class does not extend the SelectionModel?

Comment: @user11880836 A `ListView` can have properties of type `SelectionModel` right? It can return this selection model from a method. Something like `class ListView { SelectionModel selectionModel = ...; SelectionModel getSelectionModel() { return selectionModel; } }` Think about the call chain as the compiler creating temporary variables invisible to you: `MultipleSelectionModel temp1 = myListView.getSelectionModel(); ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Item> temp2 = temp1..selectedItemProperty(); temp2.addListener(...);`

Comment: @user11880836 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541477/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441090/, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/.